# AWS RDS unable to set Backup retention period with deletion protection enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform

I am trying to set up `Backup retention period` for my AWS RDS instance. The instance has enabled the option `Enable deletion protection`.

Here is my current set up in AWS console:

[image: Deletion protection]

[image: Backup]

When trying to persist these changes the modifications summary is showing that `Deletion protection` will be disabled if I set the `Backup retention period` to a value greater than 0.

[image]

However, there is no explanation for this behavior and since I am trying to manage my infrastructure with Terraform, I never got to see this.

Am I missing something in my set up, could anyone bring more clarity to this, please?

Thanks

Comment: Your question, as it stands, doesn't really show anything Terraform related. Is Terraform showing the equivalent to this in the diff when you run a plan? Can you share your Terraform code, the plan output from running it and the result and then explain what you'd want the result to be?

Comment: The issue is not really Terraform related I think, since the AWS configuration is just making changes without letting me know, I just wanted to mention Terraform since I am using the tool and it doesn't provide any messages to what is happening with the configuration.

Comment: This seems like it could be a console bug.  There is no obvious reason why enabling backup retention would need to disable deletion protection.

Comment: Indeed it was, after trying the same behaviour the very next day it was possible to persist changes without the deletion protection being disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a temporary console bug.

After trying the same behaviour the very next day it was possible to persist changes without the `Enable deletion protection` set to false.